# Searching data in database using Like with different column values possible

Tags: c#, search

Is it possible to add `StudentNumber`, `Fname`, alongside with `Lname`(those are columns from my database) using `LIKE` search query?

Here's my code:

```
DataTable dt;

private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataView dv = new DataView(dt);
    dv.RowFilter = string.Format("Lname LIKE '%{0}%'", textBox1.Text);
    dataGridView1.DataSource = dv;
}
```

That's working but only `Lname` data can be searched.

Comment: Add a column in dataview that contains the StudentNumber+Fname+ Lname and use like operator on that column

Answer (score 1):

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataView dv = new DataView(dt);
    dv.RowFilter = string.Format("(StudentNumber+Fname+Lname) LIKE '%{0}%'", textBox1.Text);
    dataGridView1.DataSource = dv;
}
```

or

Add a column in datatable that contains the Result of StudentNumber+Fname+Lname

Answer (score 0):

You cannot concatenate the fields in a single Like statement. To illustrate this, consider:

```
Fname='fname'
LName='lname'
```

and the search string `textBox1.Text='el'`

If you concatenate `Fname+Lname` you will get `fnamelname` and the search would be a match. However none of the fields `Fname` or `Lname` contain `el`.

However you can do something like this. `StudentNumber LIKE '%{0}%' or Fname LIKE '%{0}%' or Lname LIKE '%{0}%'`

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataView dv = new DataView(dt);
    dv.RowFilter = string.Format("StudentNumber LIKE '%{0}%' or Fname LIKE '%{0}%' or Lname LIKE '%{0}%'", textBox1.Text);
    dataGridView1.DataSource = dv;
}
```